# How to write iterative DFS which counts descendants of a node in a tree

Tags: c++, tree, depth-first-search, iteration, descendant

I have problem with turning this code:

```
void dfs(int i = 1) {
  static int preorder = 0;
  d[i].first = ++preorder;
  d[i].second = 1;
  for (list<int>::iterator it = tree[i].begin(); it != tree[i].end(); ++it) {
    dfs(*it);
    d[i].second += d[*it].second;
  }
}
```

into iterative one. As you can see, it finds preorder number of each node and how many descendants it has.
I have to do it, because of memory limitation (data size is up to 10^6).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a good use of a static variable...

Comment: Why? This function is called only once.

Comment: You call it recursively, so it actually gets called a lot.

Comment: Hmm maybe I misunderstand something but I think that static variable is initialized only once and it behaves just like global one (except it is not in global namespace) so what exactly do you find bad?

Only problem I can see is that next non-recursion call will be without resetting value of variable preorder. Please clarify :)

Comment: @rAum: Yes precisely.  It will not work next time you non-recursively call the function.  It also won't work properly if you're using the function in a multi-threaded situation.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ok, I get it. However that is not the problem - I run it only once in single-threaded enviroment just for precomputation to be able to answer ancestor-descendant question in O(1).
To be precisely - it is a small piece of solution for my algorithm class task - contest like style - and I can't pass the biggest test because of this recursion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figure it out. It may be not so fast but it is fast enough to get passed through tests without eating too much memory. I needed pointers from child to his father (just 8 MB array called ojciec) and detect if node is first time visited (going down) or not (going up).
Here is my code:

```
void dfs()
{
  int preorder = 0;
  int i;
  stack<int, list<int> > stos;

  stos.push(1);
  while(!stos.empty()) {
    i = stos.top();

    if (order[i] == 0) { // node is first time visited
      order[i] = ++preorder; // set default values
      size[i]  = 1;
    }

    if (dynastia[i] != NULL) // can go left...
      stos.push( pop( &dynastia[i] ) ); // so take first child, remove it and release memory
    else {
      stos.pop();
      size[ojciec[i]] += size[i]; // adding total number of descendants to father
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DFS is a recursive algorithm.

If you are trying to avoid running out of stack space, you can use an explicit stack (convert the implicit call stack into an explicit node stack). But I don't think you can get away from the fact that it's a recursive algorithm.

Even if you are using an explicit stack, you could still run out of memory. That depends on the amount of memory in your system, and the shape of the tree. But in most cases it would at least avoid a nasty crash (you can detect when you run out of heap memory).

Comment: If the nodes have parent pointers, then you don't need a stack.

Comment: I know this. I can write simple dfs using stack but I have problem with my version because I'm using backtracking to count descendants and have no idea how to make it iterative.

I have available 32 MB of RAM and in worst case I will have 10^6 nodes and tree would be just a list so it is impossible to use recurrence...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: hmm nodes doesn't have parent pointers but maybe it's right thing to try next. Thanks ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth couldn't that affect the asymptotic runtime complexity? You'd have to keep looking for the next child that hasn't been visited yet (whereas with a stack you get that for free).

Comment: @OmriBarel: I don't know about asymptotic complexity, but it will certain affect the runtime.